# How do I use weights other than bold and normal in python with tkinter

Tags: tkinter, fonts, raspberry-pi

The title says it all. I'd like to use all of the weights available with a Google font in a python program via tkinter. If it matters I'm doing this on a Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only weights that Tkinter can apply to a font are "normal" and "bold".

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_fonts.htm

Above I have shown a link to how to use fonts in tkinter I hope this helps a bit.

http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/fonts.html

Here is a link to the tkinter docs. I would recommend using Standard fonts, and also possibly using slants for italic. Also if you want to underline your fonts you can use something such as `f.configure(underline = True)`

Hope this helps a little bit.